# How to config path to log4j.properties file in Spring and JSF environment?

Tags: spring, log4j, jsf-2.2

I have maven-compatible eclipse dynamic project on windows 7.I put log4j.properties under src/main/resources/welcome

In web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>`
    <param-value>file/C:/projectpath/src/main/resources/welcome/log4j.properties </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I could not get it working when I put log4j.properties file under src directory.
What s the proper way for the config above?
Is there another way rather than this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is wrong, because you gave the absolute path.

It should be something like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Please also note that above xml snippet is not necessarily required, because `/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties` should be called automatically.

Comment: /src/main/resources/welcome/log4j.properties I am trying this one.Not auto one.If this is not possible I wan to put log4j.properties file under a common directory like C://myprops/log4j.properties and then share this with existing eclipse project.I could not find a way for those two

Answer (score 0):

Copy your **log4j.properties** file in *src*.

Change **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```